# auto scroll when content goes to maximum height of div

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, iscroll4

How do I start auto scrolling when the content goes to maximum height of a div? I am getting alert when I am at the end of the div, but is it possible to start auto scrolling?

Here is my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/JpvAy/

I found the end point of div like this:

```
 myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
              onScrollEnd: function() {
                    if(($('#wrapper').offset().top - $('#scroller').offset().top) + $('#wrapper').height() >= $('#scroller').height()){
                        alert('the end');
                    }                        

              }
        });
```

But I need to start auto scrolling when data is taller than height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this after reresh

```
myScroll.scrollTo(0, myScroll.maxScrollY, 0);
```

and also you should learn how to make fiddle so it's easy to understand the code

here is our updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JpvAy/1/)

Comment: why it is blinking up and down in starting ?

Comment: Secondly when I am using refresh before auto scrolling I have one issue .If I have  data in div and I scroll some  part but it automatically goes to top point I think because of refresh function .

Comment: Is this possible to prevent that mean I scroll some part it refresh div but should be only there where it was not going to top position

Comment: You can make some boolean for check if user scroll or not and u can stop refresh and another method if user scroll else do refresh and get him to bottom of div

Comment: and also can check just like you did before for  scroll end if user is not at end of div do nothing

Comment: can you do this on fiddle so it better understanding..?

Comment: Thanks can you look this question also.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374706/how-to-scroll-the-iscroll-at-fixed-position